# Cannot locate my projects section in IBM Watson Studio

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I had created a machine learning service on IBM cloud where I clicked on the option to access in Watson Studio. I then imported a sample project from the gallery and made some changes to notebooks there. I can see the service on IBM cloud I created but am having trouble locating the project and assets on Watson Studio.

[This is the resource I had created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdhWC.png)

[On clicking Access in Watson Studio I am redirected to this page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k86K.png).Please note that the instance name is not a link.

Comment: I assume, you saved it to that project. Correct? Have you trouble locating the project or the notebook?

Comment: I had created a machine learning service. I then imported a sample project from the gallery and made some changes to that. I can access the service I created but having trouble locating the project.

Comment: And are you in Watson Studio or IBM Cloud? dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com or cloud.ibm.com/

Comment: I created the project and made the changes on Watson Studio after created the service on IBM cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Watson Studio, click the "hamburger" icon (three horizontal lines) in the top left corner, then select *Projects* > *View All Projects* to get a list of your projects. The names in the list are links to your projects. You'll find the assets within the project.

Watson Studio is deployed into four separate regions. Please make sure to access the region in which you created your project:

- https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/  for US (Dallas)
- https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/  for UK (London)
- https://eu-de.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/  for EU/Germany (Frankfurt)
- https://jp-tok.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/  for Asia/Pacific (Tokyo)

Comment: Surprisingly, there was no option for projects in the hamburger menu in the link provided. However, going to https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/projects worked for me. Thank anyways!

Comment: Maybe the entitlement for Watson Studio is missing. Our users can enable Watson Studio and Watson Knowledge Catalog separately. In the top right, click on your initials or avatar, then _Profile and settings_. Check the _Settings_ tab whether there is a tile for Watson Studio.

Comment: This worked. I enabled Watson machine learning tab from settings tab. I can now access it directly. Thanks!